# Conditional Probability. Having problem with the semantics of the question (I guess).

Tags: probability

Following question is taken from Introduction to Probability by Dimitri. I am having trouble understanding the difference between his two statements in question (both statements are bold-faced).

If an aircraft is present in a certain area, a radar detects it and generates an alarm signal with probability 0.99. **If an aircraft is not present. the radar generates a (false) alarm**, **with probability 0. 10**. We assume that an aircraft is present with probability 0.05. **What is the probability of no aircraft presence and a false alarm**? What is the probability of aircraft presence and no detection?
A = {an aircraft is present },
B = {t he radar generates an alarm}

To me, the first bold faced statement and the second bold faced statement are the same but in the example solution, he defines first bold faced statement as:
P(B|A<sup>c</sup>)
and second bold faced statement is defined as:
P(A<sup>c</sup>nB)

Comment: The difference is that the first one denotes the probability that the radar generates an alarm given that we ALREADY KNOW that an aircraft is not present. In this case, we have already restricted to the subspace of events where an aircraft is not present. The second probability given is the probability that there is both no aircraft presence and an alarm is sounded -in this case, we have not prior knowledge that other events have occurred, which would restrict our space of outcomes to a smaller subspace.

Comment: Thanks AWertheim. I noticed also that in first statement, the probability of NO ARICRAFT PRESENCE is 1 - aircraft is never assumed to he present. This makes P(A^c) =1, and only in first case, P(B|A<sup>c</sup>) = P(BnA<sup>c</sup>). Where P(A<sup>c</sup>) in P(B|A<sup>c</sup>) = P(BnA<sup>c</sup>)/P(A<sup>c</sup>) is 1. Thanks.